# How to call PS script from another and forward variables from child to parent?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-10

I need to call one PowerShell script from another one, the child script will create some variables and I need the parent script to be able to use variables, created by child script.

How to do that?

Structure of folder is:

```
- project folder
-- service scripts folder
--- parent_script.ps1
--- child_script.ps1
--- a bunch of other sctrips, which later will use variables created by child script
-- src folder
```

The `child_script.ps1` creates a bunch of variables with locations specific for this project:

```
$SCRIPTS_FOLDER = $PSScriptRoot
$PROJECT_FOLDER = (get-item $PSScriptRoot).parent.FullName
$SOURCES_LOCATION = Join-Path -Path $PROJECT_FOLDER -ChildPath "src"
```

And that part works if I run it as separate script. But, if I call that script from another one, those variables are not forwarded t the parent one.

`parent_script.ps1`

```
Invoke-Expression -Command .\child_script.ps1
Write-Output $SCRIPTS_FOLDER 
Write-Output $PROJECT_FOLDER 
Write-Output $SOURCES_LOCATION
```

This doesn't print anything.

Is there a way for `parent_script.ps1` to use variables, created in `child_script.ps1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.

Just needed to use

```
. .\child_script.ps1
```

Instead of:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command .\child_script.ps1
```